# Увеличить отступ пунктов списка

Tags: css

Как увеличить отступ текста от номера пункта списка?

```css
.sho_ol-red, .sho_ol-black {
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: num;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.sho_ol-red li::before {
  content: counter(num) " ";
  counter-increment: num;
  color: #ff0054;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.sho_ol-black li::before {
  content: counter(num) " ";
  counter-increment: num;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="sho_ol-black">
<li>Целенаправленность при одновременной бессмысленности содержания<br/> Рыбные тексты также применяются для демонстрации различных видов шрифта и в разработке макетов. </li>
<li>Как правило их содержание бессмысленно. По причине своей функции текста-заполнителя для макетов<br/> нечитабельность рыбных текстов имеет особое значение, так как человеческое восприятие имеет особенность,<br/> распознавать определенные образцы и повторения. </li>
<li>В случае произвольного набора букв и длины слов ничто не отвлекает от оценки воздействия и читаемости<br/> различных шрифтов, а также от распределения текста на странице (макет или площадь набора). Поэтому<br/> большинство рыбных текстов состоят из более или менее произвольного набора слов и слогов. </li>
<li>Таким образом образцы повторения не отвлекают от общей картины, а шрифты имеют лучшую базу сравнения.<br/> Преимущественно конечно, если рыбный текст кажется в некоторой степени реалистичным, не искажая тем самым<br/> воздействие макета финальной публикации.</li>
```

Чтобы было как в [примере](https://clip2net.com/s/3T42ukJ). шрифт другой там, тут просто для примера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю для чего вам нужно было два псевдоэлемента но я удалил один и похоже на решение

```css
ol{
  list-style: none;
  counter-reset: num;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
li{
  display:inline-block;
  display:flex;
  margin-top:10px;
}

ol li:before {
  content: counter(num) " ";
  counter-increment: num;
  color: #ff0054;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding:0 10px;
  margin-top:-5px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Целенаправленность при одновременной бессмысленности содержания<br/> Рыбные тексты также применяются для демонстрации различных видов шрифта и в разработке макетов. </li>
  <li>Как правило их содержание бессмысленно. По причине своей функции текста-заполнителя для макетов<br/> нечитабельность рыбных текстов имеет особое значение, так как человеческое восприятие имеет особенность,<br/> распознавать определенные образцы и повторения.
    </li>
  <li>В случае произвольного набора букв и длины слов ничто не отвлекает от оценки воздействия и читаемости<br/> различных шрифтов, а также от распределения текста на странице (макет или площадь набора). Поэтому<br/> большинство рыбных текстов состоят из
    более или менее произвольного набора слов и слогов. </li>
  <li>Таким образом образцы повторения не отвлекают от общей картины, а шрифты имеют лучшую базу сравнения.<br/> Преимущественно конечно, если рыбный текст кажется в некоторой степени реалистичным, не искажая тем самым<br/> воздействие макета финальной публикации.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: а как можно цифры выровнять по верхней границе пунктов списка или наоборот, пункты списка по верхней границе цифер?

Comment: @Michael исправил - так надо ?

Comment: да, так норм, спс.